# Is it possible to create a Kafka Connector without REST request?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to create a Kafka Connector without REST request?

I have started my worker (distributed) through a java code and want my connector also gets started along with it. I dont want to use REST call (not from browser and not from code) to create my connector.
I just want a simple kafka api to invoke which creates my connector.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might look this https://www.confluent.io/blog/create-dynamic-kafka-connect-source-connectors

Comment: "a simple kafka api to invoke " -> yes, it's the REST API :) That's how you create connectors. Can you edit your question to explain why you don't want to use the REST API from your code? That's how you would programatically create a connector usually.

Comment: What do you mean you started the worker with java code?