# Create kafka connector during startup without REST API

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, connector

i have to leverage kafka connector as source but creating connector by REST api in production is something I want to avoid, is it possible to create connector during startup without using REST api?
I understand REST api provides the flexibility to dynamically create/configure connectors and size the tasks, but really want to if the same can be done during startup either by providing any configuration problem. 
Currently I start connector in distributed mode by supplying properties file and I want to mention the database, filters, transformers and other details there itself.
Let me know if there is a way to achieve.

Comment: Yep ... struggling with the same thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58849640/is-it-possible-to-create-a-kafka-connector-without-rest-request